# SQL Query to fetch records with multiple conditions and AND operators

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use a condition within a condition in query to retrieve exact set of records.
For e.g. Consider a table

```
Create table TestRecords
(Id int,
CustID int,
Category varchar(max),
CurrentStatus varchar(max)
)
```

And the below values I inserted in the table.

```
insert into TestRecords values(1,1001,'A','P');
insert into TestRecords values(2,1001,'B','P');
 insert into TestRecords values(3,1001,'C','P');
insert into TestRecords values(4,1001,'D','P');
insert into TestRecords values(5,1001,'A','F');
insert into TestRecords values(6,1002,'B','P');
insert into TestRecords values(7,1003,'C','P');
insert into TestRecords values(7,1003,'D','P');
insert into TestRecords values(7,1004,'A','P');
insert into TestRecords values(7,1004,'B','P');
insert into TestRecords values(7,1004,'D','P');
insert into TestRecords values(7,1004,'E','P');
```

Now what query should I write if I want to find the details for customer id and exact matching categories. For e.g. if I want to find customer ID with value 1001 and category should be ‘A’, B and C
I don’t want customer id with only A,B or B,C etc categories. If should satisfy all the three categories .i.e A,B,C

Things I tried

```
  select * 
  from TestRecords 
  where CustID=1004 
    and CurrentStatus='P' 
    and Category ='A' 
    and Category ='B' 
    and Category ='C'
```

I don’t want to use IN condition as it will act as a logical ‘OR’ operator and will result even if it will have values matching categories A,B or B,C or C,A

Comment: no that wont work

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to get as a results and what are your input parameters. Can you add to your question an expected result on this query on above sample data?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want to get the userId that have currentstatus 'P' with all three categories.

You can do this using aggregation:

```
select custId
from testrecords
where currentstatus='P'
and category in ('A','B','C')
group by custId
having count(distinct category) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you will have to list all the conditions. Something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM TestRecord
WHERE CustID=1004 -- or 1001, your example and your question does not match here
  AND CurrentStatus = 'P'
  AND Category IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
  AND CustID IN (
    SELECT CustID
    FROM TestRecord
    WHERE CurrentStatus = 'P'
    AND Category = 'A'
  )
  AND CustID IN (
    SELECT CustID
    FROM TestRecord
    WHERE CurrentStatus = 'P'
    AND Category = 'B'
  )
  AND CustID IN (
    SELECT CustID
    FROM TestRecord
    WHERE CurrentStatus = 'P'
    AND Category = 'C'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

this might work

```
select * from TestRecords where CustID=1001 and id in (
(select id from TestRecords where category='A') INTERSECT
(select id from TestRecords where category='B')INTERSECT
(select id from TestRecords where category='C'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an outer query and inner query .The inner query will fetch the result and give to the outer query.

```
select * from TestRecords where CustID=1001 and id in 
(
   (select id from TestRecords where category='A') 
              INTERSECT
   (select id from TestRecords where category='B')
              INTERSECT
   (select id from TestRecords where category='C')*
)
```